# How to integrate database in Firebase (Cloud Firestore) with Laravel Auth user

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check this user is unique before create it using Firestore with Laravel 
[Auth/RegisterController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhEIM.png)

[Cloud Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcoWG.png)

Comment: You need to use a [Transaction](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.12.2/firestore/transaction) in order to first read the user's `Profiles` document and if it does not exist, create it.

Comment: Thank you @RenaudTarnec , I will try then I will back soon

Comment: If an answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it (although you may not have enough reputation to do this yet). If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (which you can do, since you asked the question). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I can see from your screenshots that you are using [`kreait/firebase-php`](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) (which I like since I'm the maintainer ).

Were you aware that the SDK also has a Laravel Package? You can find it on GitHub at [github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase).

With it, you don't need to instantiate the Factory in your controller, but can use Dependency Injection or the `app()` helper to retrieve the component you need.

Since I believe that the package would be the best solution for your use case, I will continue as if you were using it ) - once configured, you could do use a transaction (as already hinted by @[Renaud Tarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841426/how-to-integrate-database-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-with-laravel-auth-user/61845260#comment109381320_61841426)) to check for uniqueness:

```php
/** @var \Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient $firestore */
$firestore = app('firebase.firestore')->database();

$firestore->runTransaction(function (Transaction $transaction) {
    // ...        
});
```

In order to make the functionality available to the validator, you should look at creating a custom rule as described on https://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules - this would probably enable you to use it as you envisioned it in your screenshot.

PS: Please consider embedding images directly in your questions, or, even better, include code snippets as text - this would make it easier to grasp the question in its entirety, and enable others to copy-paste parts of it.

Comment: Thank You a lots <3, I found solution the same as you but without transaction , and it works .Is there any benefits that transaction made which I can use instead of traditional rules validation ... and by the way your package help me  a lots , Keep Going <3

Comment: If this is feasible with rules alone, even better! Transactions would ensure that the operation doesn't fail if you first check for uniqueness, then write the document, but the document has been created somewhere from somewhere else in the meantime.